# Saving darts time series model to onnx format

Tags: python, time-series, onnx

Below is a sample of darts time series model. How can I save this model to onnx model? Is there any way to do it? Thank you.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import darts
 from darts import TimeSeries
 from darts.models import  NBEATSModel 

 #df dataset 
 date = pd.date_range(start = '01/01/2018', end = '12/29/2021', freq = 'D') 
 sales=np.random.rand(len(date))
 df=pd.DataFrame({'sales': sales}, index=date)
 df.index.name='Date'
 df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
 
 #convert time series 
 df=TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df,time_col='Date',value_cols=['sales'])

 #model
 model = NBEATSModel(input_chunk_length=24, output_chunk_length=12, n_epochs=100, 
 random_state=0)

 model.fit(df)
```